# Django template variables with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, django-templates

How to update Django for loop template variable using response data on Ajax success. The status of the object is updating in the database I just can't get it to update the template. if I remove + response.applicant_pk the template is updated but always just the first item in the for loop

```
<div id="app_status_" class="_button__base_ _blue__button">
    <strong>{{applicant.status}}</strong>
</div>

def applicant_status_change(request, applicant_id):

    response_data = {}
    if request.method =='POST' and request.is_ajax():
        try:
            applicant = Applicant.objects.get(pk=applicant_id)
            position = applicant.applied_for.id
            position = Position.objects.get(id=position)
            count = position.get_all_applied_users_count()
            applicant.status = request.POST['applicant_status']
            applicant.pk = request.POST['pk']

            response_data = {
            "applicant_status": applicant.status,
            "applicant_pk":applicant.pk
            }
            applicant.save()
            return JsonResponse(response_data)
        except Applicant.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({'status':'Fail', 'msg': 'Object does not exist'})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'status':'Fail', 'msg':'Not a valid request'})



    $(".dropdown-item").click(function (e) {

    var applicant_stat = $(this).text();
    var pk = "{{ applicant.pk }}"

    $.ajax({
      url : '/dashboard/applicant/status/{{  applicant.pk  }}/',
      type : "POST",
      data : {
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : "{{  csrf_token  }}",
        'applicant_status': applicant_stat,
        'pk': pk
      },
      success: function(response) {
        $('#app_status_'+ response.applicant_pk).empty().append(response.applicant_status);
      },
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

if it helps anyone else: I hadn't added the applicant pk to the div ID

```
<div id="app_status_{{applicant.pk}}" data-pid="{{ applicant.pk }}" class="_button__base_ _blue__button">{{applicant.status}}
</div>
```